# Pointer of char, two diffrent ways one problem

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have two different declarations of strings.

```
char * Dateiname;
char Dateiname1[LEN_ASCII_TIME];
```

In the first case I allocate memory with malloc:

```
if(Dateiname = malloc(sizeof(char)*LEN_ASCII_TIME) == NULL){
   perror(NIO_SPEICHER);
}
```

the second case = LEN_ASCII_TIME = 25
There no malloc or calloc necessary.

Then I want to use the asctime() from time.h to copy the string to filename:

```
strncpy_s(Dateiname,LEN_ASCII_TIME,asctime(sysTimeStruct),LEN_ASCII_TIME-1);
```

Output case 1:

```
(null)
```

If I used the second variant:

```
 strncpy_s(Dateiname1,LEN_ASCII_TIME,asctime(sysTimeStruct),LEN_ASCII_TIME-1);`
```

Output Variante 2:

```
Tue Mar 23 12:57:51 2021
```

Where is my thinking error? Why can't I reserve and write a memory area to the charptr * with malloc?

Comment: There'll be something wrong *somewhere* in your code. You should post a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short: this is because you tried a clever trick. If you assign the result of `malloc` outside of `if`, you would get the desired result:

```
Dateiname = malloc(LEN_ASCII_TIME);
if(Dateiname == NULL){
   perror(NIO_SPEICHER);
}
```

The reason the behavior of your code is different is that the assignment `=` has lower [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `==`, so `Dateiname` is assigned the result of comparing `malloc`-ed pointer to `NULL`, which is `0`.

Note that `sizeof(char)` is fixed to `1` by the standard, so you never need to multiply by it.

Comment: It's a common idiom rather than a "clever trick", but it needs to be used correctly.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The distance between a common idiom and a clever trick is two parentheses :-) I've been looking at C code for 35+ years, yet have it not been for the OP providing the output, I would not see a mistake in this code - at least not right away.

Comment: Thank you, this was a very helpfull answer - = has lower precedence than == -!